# remove transparent pixels in between vector images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have an eps file containing some vector images.  Is there a way in Photoshop to remove blank space in between the images?  I know about trim but this only removes space on the outside border  I want to remove all space outside and in between. Hope that makes sense.  I also have Illustrator if that helps.  Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi Bob, it may be helpful to provide a sample of the image and tell us what part is not hidden when using trim. But if the graphic is in vector format, you will want to use the path finder options in Illustrator to hide parts of the vector.

Comment: @AndrewH example image can be seen [here](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-122980387/stock-vector.html).  In other words I want to remove the whitespace in between the file type images without manually moving them.  Just wondering if there is something similar to trim for space in between.

Comment: I'm very confused about what "blank space" you are referring to and want to remove.  Do you mean that you would like it so all of the icons are touching each other?  That will have to be done manually.

Comment: Yes I want them touching each other.  I guess you have answered my question then.  My purpose was to create a sprite image and reduce file space and make the positioning a little easier for a web project.

Comment: @JohnManly There kinda is an auto way of doing this in AI and it works very nice when having a lot of icons, check out my answer.

Comment: Your proposed solution is predicated on rasterizing the image. If SVG is an option for you, consider just converting the eps to svg. If they are truly **vector, the white space has no size,** so there would be no need to optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AUTOMATICALLY ARRANGE ICONS SIDE BY SIDE

While illustrator does not provide a one click auto way of doing exactly what you want, there are a series of other functions that if combined, it will get you exactly there.

1. You have 20 icons (make sure they are grouped individually)
2. Create another artboard or document the same height as one icon but the width of 20 icons (multiply the width of one icon by the number of icons you have)
3. Copy your icons and paste them in the newly created artboard.
4. Select all of them and click from the top menu **Vertical Align Center** and then **Horizontal Distribute Center** :

[image]

And there you have it, auto-arranged, side-by-side icons.

---

### Original answer:

If you want to create a sprite for the web out of these, you can simply click on the icon you want to move and while Holding SHIFT, drag it to the left till it intersects the margin of the other icon. Holding shift locks the direction while dragging therefore it's very important. Look:

*PS: If you can't select in Illustrator each icon individually, you will have to ungroup them like I mentioned in step 4 above.*

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your comment, it wasn't what I was looking for, as I want the file types to be touching each other.  Sorry if it wasn't clear enough in my question.  John says there is no way to do this without manually moving them myself.  My hope was there was a similar effect to trim for space in between

Comment: @Bob Uhm, yes there is...I will update my question now

Comment: @Bob , Updated my question.

Comment: The SHIFT trick was very helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: @Bob , just now I saw you updated your question...there is a way of doing this much faster too. Just wait a second and I will update the answer

Comment: @Bob done. Check it out.

Comment: Brilliant, love it

Comment: @Bob awesome, it means you made it. Good for you. If this fixed your problem you will want to click the checkmark next to the answer to not show on the unanswered tab anymore. Thanks and good luck with your project.